# "database does not exist" after pg backup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I hope you re all doing great !

I got surprised today when I "rails s" my app : ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError

```
connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: database "DDH_development" does not exist
```

The last thing I did yesterday was trying to backup my database on PGadmin (I don't rememebber how it ended actually) and when I try to connect to PGadmin :

```
Connection to the server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist
```

What did I do ? I don't know where to start looking...
A few days ago, I tried to upgrade pg from 13 to 14, could it be that ?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: You must have done something more than backing up the database. The second error indicates serious trouble. If you don't remember what you did, hire a specialist who can try to salvage some data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I looked in the Library/postgresql folder but it's empty. The DBs are supposed to be there ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by library/postgresql folder. Hire an expert.